# How to convert from ASCII to string or symbol

Tags: c++

I want to output this `^` to the console, but I want to do it using ASCII code and not the value itself. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Can't you just `std::cout << static_cast<int>('^');` and use that? Or just reference an ASCII table.

Comment: Uses ASCII code to output '^' to console: `char c = 94; std::cout << c;`

Comment: and another example : std::cout << '\x5e';

Comment: If you don't want to use the caret character: `std::cout << "??'";`  This has the advantage that it is guaranteed to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 5):

That symbol is called a [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret). The ASCII code is `0x5e` in hexadecimal (= 94 in decimal).

C version:

```
printf("%c", 0x5e);
```

C++ version:

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(0x5e);
```

Both of these assume that you are running on a system where the default character encoding assigns the caret symbol the value `0x5e`.

To avoid having to rely on this assumption it is better to not use the ASCII code but instead use `'^'`.

Comment: I know hexadecimal make it look cooler, but you can also use decimal numbers there

Comment: Hmm... it was tagged C when I posted. Updated. I'll leave the C version in anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The hexadecimal value for the *caret* character (`^`) is **most often** *0x5e* (*94* in decimal).

```
std::cout << static_cast<char> (0x5e) << " " << (char)94 << " " << '\x5e';
```

<sup><sup>**output on my playform**: `"^ ^ ^"`</sup></sup>

---

I write *"most often"* because the standard **doesn't** guarantee what integer value is used to represent a certain character, therefore you shouldn't do what you are implying.

Even though it will probably work out the way you want to (since most modern *operating-system* represent *caret* using that value) it's not recommended.. if it's not in the standard no one can guarantee you that it is going to work on all platforms, in all cases.

---

#### What does the standard say?

> #### 2.3/3   Character sets   [lex.charset]
>
> The execution character set and the execution wide-character set are
> implementation-defined supersets of the basic execution character set
> and the basic execution wide-character set, respectively. **The values
> of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of
> additional members are locale-specific**.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: http://www.ascii-code.com/

It's ASCII code 0x5e.